# Texas instruments component size

Tags: pcb, components, layout, pins, texas-instruments

I am about to make a pcb footprint for this package:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/mpds049b/mpds049b.pdf

But I am not sure what the two numbers mean, for example at pin 5 that 0,30/0,15.
Are these maximum/minimum values in milimeters? Is that possible they have this huge difference between them?

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, the actual part datasheet may have suggested footprint dimensions.

Comment: It's obviously maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fully interpret this drawing, it's useful to know a bit about [GTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing) (Geometric Dimensioning and Tolerancing).

In answer to your specific question, the numbers refer to the maximum (top) and minimum (bottom) dimensions. So the leg will be somewhere between 0.15mm and 0.3mm wide.

The box around a dimension (not this one) indicates that it's a nominal dimension (such as the pitch 0.65mm) or what is called a "basic dimension" in GD&T. 
The positional tolerance of the legs is specified by the box with the 0.13mm in it and refers to maximum material condition (beyond the scope of this answer, but see the link if you're interested). In essence it allows the leg to be more out of the position dictated by the nominal pitch if it's thinner, so a 0.15mm wide leg can be more out of position than a 0.3mm wide leg. That allows the manufacturer to minimize costs, yet still retaining what matters to the user (the actual metal of the leg should fall within the target).

I agree with others that you should be able to find a suggested footprint and that this is a standard package (though not SO8 given the relatively fine pitch).

Edit: This is a DCT package, here is TI's recommended footprint for it (from the [TXS0102 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0102.pdf)):

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0102.pdf]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share your (apparently) unlimited knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The script 0,30/0,15 refers to the width of the pin coming from the package and basically means that the minimum width is 0.15mm and the maximum width is 0.30mm.

It's not that critical (on many chips) what the width is providing it isn't a pin that carries several amps of current.

Some dimensions are not shown this way - typically the inter-pin distance - this is set in stone for this size SO package.